# the proper way to listen for server sending attempt

Tags: java, sockets

what is the proper way to determine that the server is sending data at the moment for example
Pseudo-code

```
while(true){
  //Do something
  if(ServerIsSendingrightnow){
    //Get The Data
    //Calling some method to handling the server's data
  }
  //Do something else
}
```

does the method available() of InputStream class do the job ?
Code:

```
 while(true){
   //Do something
   InputStream IStreamsock = Socket1.getInputStream();
   if(IStreamsock.available()){ //the server is sending data right now !
     //Get The Data
     //Calling some method to handling the server's data}
     //Do something else
}
```

In C# we have MemoryStream class that serve as Dynamic byte array
is there any java equivalent for MemoryStream
can I do something like this in java:
Pseudo-code

```
 while(DataIsAvailableInSocketInputStreamBuffer){
   MemoryStreamEquivalent.WriteByte(IStreamsock.ReadByte())}
```

I'm Sorry, but I'm new comer in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an answer how you could do this:
(I wrote a complete example run() method of the client thread

```
@Override
public void run() {
   while(client.isConnected()) {  //client.isConnected should be a method of your client class
      Object inputData = in.read(); //you should use a proper Object type here, if you
                                    //use InputStreamReader, it would be Byte and if you
                                    //use BufferedReader it would be String
      doCrazyStuff(inputData);      //just an example of manipulating data, do your own stuff here
   }
}
```

Here an example with BufferedReader (I will not change the encoding or something, because I think this is just a training application)

```
public void run() {
   while(client.isConnected()) {  //client.isConnected should be a method of your client class
      while(!in.ready()) { }        //here you CAN use the method ready, that is boolean

      String inputData = in.readLine();
      doCrazyStuff(inputData);      //just an example of manipulating data, do your own stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to determine if there are data available from the server or not public void run(){ //something before reading the data while(true){ InputStream IStreamSocket = Sck.getInputStream(); /*here is the condition I'm asking for */ if(DataIsAvailableSomeHow){//read the data} hope you understand my question,thank you

Comment: Well, if you only want to DETERMINE wether there is data or not, it is going to become complicated. If you'd use BufferedReader instead of InputStreamReader, you can use inputStream.ready(), it will return true if data is available. But with the available()-function of InputStream, I don't know how to solve this problem, because, I think this method is very inconsistent and always throws an exception, if no data is available.

Comment: thank you for your Patience, thank you, may be I Will asking you more questions later ..

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the usage of available is not very useful, because it does not work as you would expect it. Just use in.read(). It will wait until something is sended by the server. So if you use it in a thread, it just waits until something can be recieved.

Edit: It recieves just one Byte, so e.g. a BufferedReader (to read Strings) is a better solution, or maybe an ObjectInputReader (for Objects, obviously). And of course the while(true) is needed :)

Comment: available does not work *reliably* as you would expect. In some cases it does

Comment: Yeah, but everytime I use it, it simply causes many many exceptions.

Comment: `available` tells you how much data can be read without blocking. This might not be what you want to know/expect, but it is quite reliable at providing this data.

Comment: thank you Cydhra, in.read(), do you mean InputStream.read()?,as this method will block the thread until data is available for reading, what if the Socket lose the connection while the method read trying to read something from the socket stream buffer  ? Isn't this a problem ?

Comment: It will throw an IOException

Comment: @BrettOkken no it isn't. I've found streams (I think it was CipherInputStream) that always report "1" as the number of bytes available from the stream, but where many more bytes can be grabbed using read(byte[])

Comment: @Cydhra can you please tell me what the condition should I use in the while loop, while(DataIsAvailable){//DoSomeThing}

Comment: Just like this:
Edit: whoops, I hit enter
Edit: I will post it as an answer

Comment: @ControlAltDel, we are talking specifically about a SocketInputStream. Also, your example is not really meaningful. Nothing about `read(byte[])` guarantees that no blocking will occur. So it is quite possible that 1 byte is available without blocking and a read call with a byte[] will read more than 1 byte. Additionally, that is not the behavior of cipher input stream - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.java#282

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
Socket s = new Socket(...); // connect to server
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(s.getInputStream()); // creating a bufferedReader around the inputstream. If you're dealing with binary data, you shouldn't create a (Buffered)Reader
while (String line = br.readLine()) {
  //do something here
}
```

Comment: This makes a couple of assumptions which may not be safe. The first is that the default character encoding of the platform is used. If the socket communication is not from the local host (which is unlikely), this is a bad assumption. The second is that the data has meaningful line endings.

Comment: primarily, I want to read byte array as I mentioned above, but thank you,can you please tell me if there is an java equivalent for c# memory stream class "dynamic byte array "

Comment: java.nio.ByteBuffer would probably be the equivalent